# UK: Letting rooms in your home through your own, limited company

Tags: united-kingdom, business, rental-property

I own and live in a house in UK with more rooms than I need, so I can rent out the surplus rooms. In UK there is a government scheme ([HS223](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rent-a-room-for-traders-hs223-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs223-rent-a-room-scheme-2022)) that would allow me to earn £7500 per year tax-free, but I can probably make significantly more than that, so I am thinking about perhaps doing it another way:

Rent the rooms to my own, limited company for a nominal rent, as described in [this article](https://www.startupdonut.co.uk/tax-and-national-insurance/how-to-work-out-tax-and-ni/save-money-by-renting-a-room-in-your-home-to-your-business), then pay salaries, small enough to be tax exempt, to my wife and/or children, and claim this as expenses for the company along with other expenses. The company will generate income by subletting the rooms.

Would this be legal? And will it be better in terms of profitability?

Comment: How does the company generate the revenue to pay the rent and salaries?

Comment: What about the [capital gains tax](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-home/let-out-part-of-home) when you sell?

Comment: @weathervane Sell what, the house? The company? How is this relevant?

Comment: @DaleM presumably by subletting the rooms to third party tenants at a margin.

Comment: @JosephP. when the house is sold. The relevance: *will it be better in terms of profitability?* The linked UK government page shows a break-even example for one room rented out, but OP's plan is to *make significantly more than that* and should consider the CGT liability.

Comment: @DaleM Yes, I should have mentioned that - the company will then sublet the rooms.

Comment: [1/2] Simply put: OP lets to -> LtdCo who sublets to -> tennant who pays -> LtdCo who pays -> OP & family. There are too many variables to offer an answer so I suggest you see an accountant...

Comment: [2/2] ... is there a secured loan on the property? If so, is this arrangement within the terms of the mortgage? Will your wife/children be directors, guarantors, employees, sub-contractors and/or shareholders? How will they be paid - drawings,  directors' loan, PAYE, post-CT dividends, gross by contract etc? Will they perform any duties or functions or are their payments merely a device to manipulate the balance sheet to extract pre-taxable profits from the accounts? NB there's a fine line between tax/NIC avoidance and evasion.

Comment: Paying salaries to someone who isn’t actually working for the company will get you into trouble for tax evasion.